# How to compile a Mustache variable before the HAML compiles

Tags: backbone.js, view, haml, mustache

My Backbone view is passing a variable called `locationCurrentTimeZone`, which is just a string. For example: `'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'`.

This is successfully being passed to the view. I can render it as html and see the string correctly. However I'm having trouble getting it to interpolate as Ruby into the `time_zone_select` helper.

I've tried all the combos of interpolation I could think of. My guess is HAML is being compiled before Mustache, so the variable hasn't been properly unwrapped from Javascript land yet.

The file name is: `myfile.mustache.haml`

Thanks for any tips. (Bonus points if you know how to add css styling to the options of this Rails helper. I've only been able to find out how to style the `select` itself)

```
.dropdown.inline-block.clearfix.valign-t
  - time_zones = [ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Hawaii'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Alaska'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Pacific Time (US & Canada)'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Arizona'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Mountain Time (US & Canada)'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Central Time (US & Canada)'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Indiana (East)'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Atlantic Time (Canada)']]
  = time_zone_select "user", "time_zone", time_zones, {default: "{{locationCurrentTimeZone}}"}, class: "dropdown-option"
```

Comment: So you're using HAML to produce a Mustache template and your Backbone view is filling in the Mustache template?

Comment: @muistooshort: sounds correct. Backbone renders the template initially.

Comment: Then wouldn't you have to handle the default value in Backbone? `time_zone_select` is going to be called by HAML and it will see the string `'{{locationCurrentTimeZone}}'` as your chosen default, the `locationCurrentTimeZone` won't be known until your Backbone view is filling in the Mustache template to produce HTML.